# inflated view's id will be repalced by fragment's id after attached?

Tags: android, fragment, getview

I created a fragment inside the activity's layout file. For eg:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <fragment android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
        android:name="com.user.domain.ArticleFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and inflate a view in `ArticleFragment::onCreateView` function:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
}
```

ariticle_view layout xml looks as below:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/article"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</TextView>
```

**Issue is here:** 
why I can only find the view through fragment's id (`R.id.article_fragment`) not view's id (`R.id.article`) after attached, and view instance's id also changed to fragment's id.

Can anybody help to explain the strange behavior?

Document for fragments api has such a description:

```
The system inserts the View returned by the fragment directly in place of the <fragment> element.
```

Does that the reason for this issue?

Comment: Means you wanna find a id for article_fragment???

Comment: I wanna get view instance after view created

Comment: You can make global variable for View and reference that instance to your returned view in `onCreateView()` method.

Comment: Yes, we can do that in `onCreateView()` method. I'm just curious that why view instance's id changed to fragment's id after created?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find you `Fragment`'s child `Views` like

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
TextView yourText = v.findViewById(R.id.article);
return v;
}
```

Comment: Yes, we can store the view instance by view's id in `OnCreateView` function, but we can also get the view's instance by fragment's id after view created.

Comment: In this case **v** IS the TextView because it is the parent.

Comment: oh, I missed this point. Have you tried to cast the inflated `View` to a `TextView`?